# Creating an empty data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create an empty data frame in R using the following code:

```
 data <- data.frame(ticks = numeric(0), identity = numeric(0), p-h = numeric(0), p-y = numeric(0), v-x = numeric(0), v-y = numeric(0), size = numeric(0), homo = numeric(0))
```

**ANSWER TO ABOVE:**
change - to _ simply.

**THOUGH I GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR WHEN ADDING DATA:**

```
Error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(value, n, p) : data length exceeds size of matrix
```

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating this empty data.frame because you plan to fill it row by row? That's really not a good idea in R. There are almost always better alternatives.

Comment: @MrFlick. Yes I do. I corrected the code but I get the following error   Error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(value, n, p) : data length exceeds size of matrix

Comment: Well, now I have no idea what code you are running. But this general strategy sounds flawed. If you have a new question, start a new post.

Comment: @MrFlick OKay will do so but I can only after 90 minutes :(. It shows "You can only post once every 90 minutes."

Comment: @MrFlick Please see the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051528/error-in-adding-rows-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-r . Added it as a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that you should, but you can use backticks to get your command to work:

```
 data <- data.frame(ticks = numeric(0), identity = numeric(0), 
   `p-h` = numeric(0), `p-y` = numeric(0), `v-x` = numeric(0), 
   `v-y` = numeric(0), size = numeric(0), homo = numeric(0))
```

But it changes the names:

```
#[1] ticks    identity p.h      p.y      v.x      v.y      size     homo    
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Please see the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051528/error-in-adding-rows-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-r . Added it as a new question

Answer (score 3):

`p-h` is "p minus h". Name your variable in a different way, i.e. `p_h` or `ph`.

Comment: Please see the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051528/error-in-adding-rows-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-r . Added it as a new question